# Check if object is deletable

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, http

I'm at the moment making an angular webapplication with an REST api. I'm having a list of object which I request from my REST api. I've implemented a delete function to delete object from the list with a delete request. What I'd also like to implement is a check function which is able to check those objects before they are deleted if it is even possible to delete them but I don't know how to do this. Does anybody know how to write such a check function?

Comment: What do you mean by list of objects?? Is it array?

Comment: In my case yes, it is an array. But it could be any way to store the data requested from the service

Comment: You need to show your code buddy. All texts are too vague.

Comment: There is no code, because I'm asking if there is a way, like a request, to figure it out if an object with id xxx is deletable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 'some other way' to communicate this type of information to a client. Your API could for instance just add a `deletable` property on the resource, determined by the server.

If you're looking for more of a standards approach, you *could* also implement an `OPTIONS` requests that returns an `Allow` header that contains a list of HTTP methods that the client may execute.

Comment: A little description: my REST API is getting its data from an SQL database. So if there is a relationship between two tables, for example one row is referring to another with an foreign key, I'm not able to delete that row. I would be able to get that information with an OPTIONS request?

Comment: No you will need to implement this yourself on the backend. There is basically no magic feature to allow this. You have to actually write the logic on the server.

Comment: Hmm...too bad. I thought, that there might be a way. Thank you :)